# Unable to add a doctrine subcriber tag in compilation pass

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a simple subscriber like the following:

```php
namespace App;

use Doctrine\Common\EventSubscriber;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\OnFlushEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Events;

class TestSubscriber implements EventSubscriber
{
    public function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            Events::onFlush,
        ];
    }

    public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $eventArgs): void
    {
        // Some stuff
    }
}
```

When I add the Doctrine subscriber tag in a compilation pass, the `onFlush` method is never trigerred:

```php
namespace App\DepencyInjection\Compiler;

use App\TestSubscriber;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Definition;

class TestSubscriberPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $definition = new Definition(TestSubscriber::class);
        $definition->addTag('doctrine.event_subscriber');
        $container->setDefinition('app.test_subscriber', $definition);
    }
}
```

But if I declare the tag in the `services.yaml`, it works well:

```yaml
services:
    app.test_subscriber:
        class: App\TestSubscriber
        tags:
            - { name: 'doctrine.event_subscriber' }
```

What am I missing ? The compilation pass is executed with success, but the tag seems to be ignored. This problem occurs even if I disable autowiring for the TestSubscriber class.

Here is the `debug:container` command output:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution:
The compilation pass must be executed before Doctrine compilation, so I set a priority grower than 0 in the compilation pass declaration in `Kernel.php`:

```php
final class Kernel extends BaseKernel
{
    use MicroKernelTrait;
    
    protected function build(ContainerBuilder $container): void
    {
        $container->addCompilerPass(new TestSubscriberPass(), PassConfig::TYPE_BEFORE_OPTIMIZATION, 100);
    }
}
```